# Change origin of UserControl placed in a Canvas

Tags: wpf, user-controls, canvas

I have a UserControl that I'm positioning on a Canvas control using Canvas.Left() and Canvas.Top(). By default the origin of the UserControl is top left (0,0). How can I move the origin of the UserControl to be bottom left?

Answer (score 2):

For that you can use the [Bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.bottom.aspx) attached property, instead of the Top. You can still use the Left property, like you are.